# button id="reset" reserved word or browser bug?

Tags: jquery

Why a click handler of a button with id="reset" does not allow me to reset form? If I change id to reset2, all works.
It is a reserved word or a IE11 bug?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/spkdN/18/
change id to reset2 to see it working

```
$(function(){


    $("#reset").click(function(e){
        document.getElementById("form").reset();
    });

});
```

Comment: I know I have read this somewhere on SO, but how ID works in the DOM is what it does is doing a getElementById and will find the #reset in this case.. and because its a DOM referense its not a method. You should avoid naming elements to dom element methods. In your case why use JS at all? why not use the `type="reset"`?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp...check here for list of reserved words